# Can Roslyn be installed on VS Community Edition?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, vs-community-edition

I'm getting a "Setup Failed" "A compatible version of Visual Studio was not detected... You must have Visual Studio 2012..."

Is it incompatible with VS2013? Or perhaps with the Community Edition? (I have VS2013 Community Edition) I don't see anything about that in the  [System Requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34685).

Comment: That's a really old version that you almost certainly shouldn't be using.

Comment: @hvd Thanks.Assuming you mean the Roslyn version - I got the link from Google+Bing! (I thought I couldn't be any more careful than that...) So how do I get the new version?

Comment: use vs2015, any edition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you look a [little further](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34685):

> Required Pre-installed Products:
>
> - Visual Studio 2012
> - Visual Studio 2012 SDK

Also, from the [Github project](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn):

> Roslyn is no longer available for Visual Studio 2013

Assuming you have a version of Visual Studio 2015 available, the easiest way to get Rosyln is probably the NuGet package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Pre
```

Comment: That seems like a contradiction (assuming VS2013 is no less than VS2012). And why would the download link in my question still be active? (I know this is not a question on your answer, rather on MS...:)

Comment: One last point, if you do want to use it you need to use [Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx) (you said what you can't use but never listed what you could use)

Comment: @ispiro I was talking to Tieson, not you. At the time of the comment he did not have any info in the answer about how to get it to work in VS2015.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sorry. I misunderstood. Thanks for the help!